# UITableView with Activity indicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I just want to display huge amount of Local Data(sqlite3 database) in to a tableView, while it was loading I want to display activity indicator and after loading I just want disable it, but it was not working. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You need to update your question with the code you have to date -  otherwise there's not a lot we can do to help in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even use the table cell accessoryView, in this case the activity indicator will be placed on the right of the cell (in place of the ">" disclosure). When the action related to the activity indicator terminates, you can replace the activity indicator with the standard disclosure accessory.

Answer (score 2):

you can add activity indicator as table cells sub view..[Adding activity indicator on table cell](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/showing-activity-indicator-spinner-in-table-cells.html)
Refer this